# Time to decimal calculation of 25,26 and 27 hours

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the above data frame and I would like to convert column time into a 24 hour format one

```
Input data:

  id time
  1 4.000000
  2 4.166667
  3 4.333333
  4 4.500000
  5 4.666667
  6 4.833333   



Output data:

    id    time Newtime
      1 4.000000 04:00
      2 4.166667 04:10
      3 4.333333 04:20
      4 4.500000 04:30
      5 4.666667 04:40
      6 4.833333 04:50
```

I tried the above code, it works but when I convert `03:00 or 02:00 even 01:00` I receive some odd results

```
Some odd results:

time            Newtime               Expected Time
26.333333       26:19.9999999999999   02:20
26.500000       26:30                 02:30
26.666667       26:40.0000000000001   02:40
26.833333       26:49.9999999999999   02:50
27.000000       27:00                 03:00 
27.166667       27:10.0000000000001   03:10
27.333333       27:19.9999999999999   03:20
27.500000       27:30                 03:30
27.666667       27:40.000000000000    03:40



 Code:

    library(string)

df1$newtime<-paste(df1$time %/% 1, str_pad(60 * (df1$time - (df1$time %/% 1)), width = 2, pad = 0), sep = ":")
```

Sample data:

```
df1<-structure(list(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), time=c("4.000000","4.166667","4.333333","4.500000","4.666667","4.833333")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

`dput` from the original data:

```
dput(df3[1:40,])
structure(list(`Day of the week` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"), class = "factor"), 
    time = c(4, 4.16666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 4.5, 4.66666666666667, 
    4.83333333333333, 5, 5.16666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 
    5.5, 5.66666666666667, 5.83333333333333, 6, 6.16666666666667, 
    6.33333333333333, 6.5, 6.66666666666667, 6.83333333333333, 
    7, 7.16666666666667, 7.33333333333333, 7.5, 7.66666666666667, 
    7.83333333333333, 8, 8.16666666666667, 8.33333333333333, 
    8.5, 8.66666666666667, 8.83333333333333, 9, 9.16666666666667, 
    9.33333333333333, 9.5, 9.66666666666667, 9.83333333333333, 
    10, 10.1666666666667, 10.3333333333333, 10.5), Total = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 9, 9, 
    14, 17, 17, 23, 31, 31, 36, 41, 41, 48, 49, 48, 50, 52, 54, 
    53, 53, 53, 52, 53), Percent = c(0.0144927536231884, 0.0144927536231884, 
    0.0144927536231884, 0.0144927536231884, 0.0144927536231884, 
    0.0144927536231884, 0.0144927536231884, 0.0144927536231884, 
    0.0144927536231884, 0.0289855072463768, 0.0289855072463768, 
    0.0434782608695652, 0.0434782608695652, 0.0434782608695652, 
    0.0579710144927536, 0.072463768115942, 0.0869565217391304, 
    0.0869565217391304, 0.130434782608696, 0.130434782608696, 
    0.202898550724638, 0.246376811594203, 0.246376811594203, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.449275362318841, 0.449275362318841, 
    0.521739130434783, 0.594202898550725, 0.594202898550725, 
    0.695652173913043, 0.710144927536232, 0.695652173913043, 
    0.72463768115942, 0.753623188405797, 0.782608695652174, 0.768115942028985, 
    0.768115942028985, 0.768115942028985, 0.753623188405797, 
    0.768115942028985), newtime = c("4:00", "4:10", "4:20", "4:30", 
    "4:40", "4:50", "5:00", "5:10", "5:20", "5:30", "5:40", "5:50", 
    "6:00", "6:10", "6:20", "6:30", "6:40", "6:50", "7:00", "7:10", 
    "7:20", "7:30", "7:40", "7:50", "8:00", "8:9.99999999999996", 
    "8:20", "8:30", "8:40", "8:50", "9:00", "9:9.99999999999996", 
    "9:20", "9:30", "9:40", "9:50", "10:00", "10:9.99999999999996", 
    "10:20", "10:30")), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: The ones you showed that are not returning expected, what is the expected i.e. for `26.333333`

Comment: @akrun thanks for  26.333333  the conversion would be  02:20

Comment: IN that case you may need to reset it back `%/% 24`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to reset to 24 hour and it can be done with `%/% 24`

```
v1 <- df1$time %%24
paste(floor(v1), round((as.numeric(v1)-floor(v1))*60), sep=":")
#[1] "2:20" "2:30" "2:40" "2:50" "3:0"  "3:10" "3:20" "3:30" "3:40"
```

Or to make sure that we have fixed widths

```
sprintf('%02d:%02d', floor(v1), round((as.numeric(v1)-floor(v1))*60))
#[1] "02:20" "02:30" "02:40" "02:50" "03:00" "03:10" "03:20" "03:30" "03:40"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(time = c(26.333333, 26.5, 26.666667, 26.833333, 
27, 27.166667, 27.333333, 27.5, 27.666667), Newtime = c("26:19.9999999999999", 
"26:30", "26:40.0000000000001", "26:49.9999999999999", "27:00", 
"27:10.0000000000001", "27:19.9999999999999", "27:30", "27:40.000000000000"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```